# No spinner in scenebuilder

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

When I try to build a spinner in FXML in JavaFX. And when I open the scene builder 2.0, I can't find the spinner option in it.

[Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlu2X.jpg)

It does have spinner in IntelliJ IDEA built-in scenebuilder. But that function always having problem. It doesn't work well.

After I added the spinner into fxml, and try to open it in scene builder, it will popup a box shows open operation failed.
Here is the detail:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/.../Desktop/Stage/src/sample/sample.fxml

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/.../Desktop/Sample%20Stage/src/sample/sample.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2864)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2708)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
at 
com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
... 22 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.Spinner
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2932)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2921)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2862)
... 27 more
```

Any idea what could cause that problem, or this kind bug. And how do I fix it. But I certainly do not want to write pure code in text page. I need to use it a lot, and text page makes me dazzled.

Comment: Try using a more recent version of Scene Builder - the development has been taken over by Gluon a fairly long time ago: https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to run this with an old JDK/JavaFX version. Make sure you are using at least JDK 1.8.0 update 40.

Comment: I did use the latest jdk version 1.8 update 141, and scenebuilder, oracle only privide the 2.0 version, which did not include the spinner. And gluonhq version actually works here, thanks.